# Move Column, Filter popover to different position in MUI Data Grid Pro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm utilizing the MUI Data Grid Pro to display my data. By default, Data Grid Pro displays the toolbar on the left side. While I successfully moved the toolbar to the right side, the popovers and menus still remained on the left. My goal is to relocate the popovers and menus to the right side, alongside my toolbar.

I tried to fix it with the following code:

```
<GridToolbarContainer>
  <GridToolbarFilterButton ref={setFilterButtonEl} />
</GridToolbarContainer>

<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
     Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
  }}
  componentsProps={{
    panel: {
      anchorEl: filterButtonEl,
    },
    toolbar: {
      setFilterButtonEl,
    },
  }}
/>
```

But this is giving me an error: maximum depth reach infinite redendering issues.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this:

```
<DataGrid
  componentsProps={{
    panel: {
      anchorEl: filterButtonEl,
      placement: "bottom-end"
    },
  }}
/>
```

[Source](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/5491#issuecomment-1185815781).

Also note that at this time `componentProps` have been deprecated in favor of `slotProps`.